# Go To Definition (F12) not working when step definitions are used from a different assembly

Tags: c#, specflow

Go To Definition (F12) is not working when step definitions are used from a different assembly. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: What do you mean by 'is not working'? Do you want to use F12 in Visual Studio to go to the Step Definition? Is VS saying there is no step definition and classifies it as inconclusive? Or is it 'not working' in another way?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific.Do you want to use F12 in Visual Studio to go to the Step Definition? Yes. Is VS saying there is no step definition and classifies it as inconclusive? Yes

Comment: And what happens if you try to run the test(s)?

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be a bug or something like that in Specflow. I have the exact same problem. When trying to go to the Step Definition from the feature file, Visual Studio says there's no matching step binding. Although, when trying to run the test(s), they run like they should, so Specflow can indeed find (and use) the matching step definitions.

Comment: running tests is not a problem as you have mentioned.

Comment: I too have this issue, with SpecFlow tests and Bindings all in the same assembly. Still a problem with 1.9

Answer (score 1):

Bindings in external assemblies are not fully supported in the SpecFlow 1.8 Visual Studio Extension. It is stated in their documentation [here](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Use-Bindings-from-External-Assemblies). SpecFlow supports them, but the Visual Studio Extension does so only partially. I am unsure whether 1.9 resolves this issue or not.

Answer (score 1):

It might be obvious, but make sure you install the SpecFlow extension.

Tools -> Extensions/Updates -> Online -> Search for "Specflow"

Comment: It is obvious, but it helped me. I just switched dev machines and forgot to check if Specflow was already installed there. So, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know i am a little late for dinner, but seems like SpecFlow stores all it's binding data in the user's %temp% folder, and those files are simple .json files that map between feature files and steps files.

So, when the steps are in the same solution as your .feature files - SpecFlow is able to detect the correct source file and the exact location of the step method.

But, when the steps are in a referenced dll, the .json config files are not enough to locate the metadata in the dll, hence F12 is not working.

I am guessing this would require some sort of design-time reflection on the referenced assemblies to make F12 work.

Answer (score 0):

@ShonnLyga thanks a lot that was really useful

To reference the assemblies from a DLL you can now use

```
<specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="NUnit" />
    <stepAssemblies>
      <stepAssembly assembly="YourDLLname" />
    </stepAssemblies>
</specFlow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above answer - sometimes I find that my steps do not get correctly mapped and I cannot click through the step to the methods.

What works for me is navigating to %temp% folder and searching for "specflow-stepmap" files in my temp folder. These take a little while to load but when they do I delete any files in here that are found for result and close and reopen visual studio. This normally will then remap the steps for me. Once remapped Go to definition on press F12 works again if this has worked.